# General Topology Question

Tags: general-topology

$Y = [-1, 1]$ induced by the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$.

$A = (-1, -1/2)\cup(1/2, 1)$ and $B = (-1, -1/2]\cup[1/2, 1)$.

a) Are $A$ and $B$ open or closed in Y with the subspace topology?

b) Are $A$ and $B$ open or closed in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology?

My attempt at an answer:

a) $(0, 1)$ is open in $Y$ and $(0, 1)\cap A = (1/2, 1)$ which is open in $Y$ so intersection of open sets in topological space is open implies $A$ is open. Complement of $A$ in $Y = A^C = \{-1\}\cup[-1/2, 1/2]\cup \{1\}$ which is closed so $A$ is not closed. So $A$ open in $Y$ and not closed in $Y$.

$B$ is not open in $Y$ because it doesn't contain a neighbourhood of its points, namely $\{-1/2\}$ and $\{1/2\}$. Complement of $B$ in $Y = B^C = \{-1\}\cup(-1/2, 1/2)\cup \{1\}$ which is also not open so $B$ is not closed. So $B$ neither open or closed in $Y$.

I want to know if I'm on the right track here. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just because $U\cap V$ is open doesn't mean $U$ and $V$ are open - for instance $[0,2)\cap(1,3]=(1,2)$ which is open in the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Also, just because $A^C$ is closed doesn't mean $A$ isn't closed. (It happens to be not closed in this case but your reasoning is wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I see those errors now. Could I say (-1, -1/2) and (1/2, 1) are open and so their union must be open, by definition of a topological space? Is there a "go-to" method for showing a set is not closed in a topological space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) can be shortened by noting that $A$ is open in $\Bbb R$, thus its intersection with $Y$, which is $A$ itself, is open in $Y$. Then you say that the complement $Y-A$ is closed and deduce that $A$ cannot be closed in $Y$, but there are subsets in $\Bbb R$ where a set can be both open and closed at the same time. You should give a reason that $Y$ is not among such sets. But you can also show it directly, by finding a point in the closure which is not in $A$ itself.

As for the set $B$ you are right that it is neither open nor closed in $Y$, as you cannot find a neighborhood for $1/2$ within $B$ nor a neighborhood for $1$ in $Y-B$. One subtlety that should be noted is that you are using **neighborhoods relative to $Y$**. But a set $N⊆Y,N\ni y$ is a neighborhood of $y$ relative $Y$ if and only if it can be written as $N'\cap Y$ where $N'$ is a neighborhood of $y$ in the whole space (Try to prove it!)

Comment: This was very helpful thank you. One more thing that is confusing me: how do we know A is open in R? Is it because it contains a neighbourhood of its points? IF so, why can't we make a similar argument for openness of A in Y?

Comment: $A$ is a union of open intervals, thus open. I don't know how exactly you define the topology in $\Bbb R$. Depending on that, an open interval is either open by definition or because it is a neighborhood of each of its elements. And since a subset of $Y$ is defined as open in $Y$ iff it's the intersection of an open set in $\Bbb R$ with $Y$, it is easiest to use the openness of $A$ in $\Bbb R$, I'd say.